# Localized modelvalidation not working in ie < 9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, model-validation

I'm using localized modelvalidation in my mvc 3 application. I did this with the Required attribute and a errormessage resource. This works on almost all browsers, except ie 7 and 8. Below you can find the sample code that I used.

Sample code:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_field_is_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global))]
    [StringLength(90, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_max_string_90", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation module has issues with some versions of jquery. I went back to the original version and it works again.